# is it possible to increase the xorg log backup level in ubuntu?

Tags: xorg, logrotate

I thought it was 3 before. But right now it only keeps Xorg.0.log and Xorg.0.log.old. Can I increase it to 10 or some other value?

It seems the logrotate does not affect the Xorg.0.log at all.

## updates

I had:

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
{
    rotate 12
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

I suspect because the x server will refresh the log file at each session, so it never got chance to rotate daily. Is there any option I can do rotation for each session?

I got inspired from [this](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/understanding-logrotate-utility) article. He suggested to create our own cron job for more frequent logrotate than daily. I might be able to create a cron job for each `boot`. But I have no idea if the Xorg got start before the job executed or after.

Comment: You can configure the retention of logs with logrotate. What's the content of /etc/logrotate.d?

Comment: @blissini please see the updates

Comment: What's the size of Xorg.0.log.old?

Comment: usually small 20k-100k or something.